# Laravel installing Error: Missing Php Extension

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

When I get to try install laravel, it returns me error in the below

> composer global require "laravel/installer"

Error:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-php-remctl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I'm using ubuntu 17.10, How can fix that error ? I tried to install that php packets but still same..

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-zip`

Comment: It says it needs the zip extension. That's provided by `phpX-zip` where X is your version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].
```

Composer is telling you that a missing extension is blocking the process.

Try to execute `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` (or 7.1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

Comment: The author is using PHP 7, not 5. And he should restart php-fpm, not the web-server

Comment: @Ryosaku if the author run php as an cgi module, he has to restart apache and not php-fpm - but thats not part of the question/solution

Comment: thanks. it worked.